# Asus G53SW weird touchpad behaviour

Tags: touchpad, asus

My friend has a new Asus G53SW notebook with Ubuntu Oneiric installed. Sometimes the touchpad is weird and hangs around or you can't click on things. It's quite unusable.

How can I fix this weird behaviour, are there any "drivers" for the touchpad?

Comment: Do you know if this is working ok on another OS? Maybe try booting with the LiveCD and check if the same behavior exists. Add more information to the question it self instead of comments please, make life easier to all of us.

Comment: This behaviour is only on Ubuntu, live and fix install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weird behaviour was from Grab Handler in CCSM.
So I just disabled Grab Handler and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Install the package synaptics-dkms and configure in System > Preferences > Mouse, under the Touchpad tab.

Try the touchpad after unchecking the Enable mouse clicks with touchpad check box.

Check operation after Enable horizontal scrolling is checked. This may not have been the default setting.

Comment: The package synaptics-dkms doesn't exist in my repositories. Where can I download this one?

Comment: Please find it in here, as also more information for your problem: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Comment: Did not help but I know the solution now.